# Regex:How can I match a last name that may have a dash, but if it does have a dash, it can only contain 1

Tags: java, regex

The title says it all, but I will provide an example.

```
ex. "Fred Hendricks" True
ex. "Casey Vegies-fish" True
ex. "Casey Veg-ie-s" False
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
^(((Mr.\s)|(Mrs.\s)|(Ms.\s)|(Dr.\s)|(Hon.\s)|(Prof.\s))?[a-zA-Z]+)\s(([A-Z][.][ ]))?([a-zA-Z]+((\sJr.)|(\sPh.D.)|(\sM.D.)|(\sII)|(\sIII)|(\sIV))?)$
```

Comment: disregard the Mr., Mrs. etc. and the Jr. Ph.D. etc. That's all working fine, at least I think

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a case where you have to enforce boundaries at the same time
allowing words *and* dash, but no more than 2 dashes in the middle.

In order to do this you have to enforce that the dash does not qualify as a
a word boundary at the beginning nor end.
While at the same time, allowing it in the middle.

*Note - you could use a whitespace boundary instead of a word boundary.

`(?<!\S) .. (?!\S)`. in place of the `(?<!-)\b .. \b(?!-)`.

This is the better option.*

`(?<!-)\b(?!(?:[^\W-]*-){2})\w(?:-?\w)*\b(?!-)`

Formatted:

```
 (?<! - )
 \b                            # Word boundary, but not a dash behind
 (?!                           # Not 2 or more dashes in this word
      (?: [^\W-]* - ){2}
 )
 \w                            # Starts with a word char
 (?:                           # Optional many dash then word char
      -?     
      \w 
 )*
 \b                            # Word boundary, but not a dash ahead
 (?! - )
```

Answer (score 1):

The part of your expression which matches the last name is `[a-zA-Z]+`. You can adjust it to accept one dash by changing it to `[a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?`, using the quantifier `?` (once or not at all).